# Ho to export external library

Tags: ros, external-libraries, cmake, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a library in OpenCV where I implemented some image processing.
The *.so file i copied to /usr/local/lib. I'm still using **Fuerte**.
I want to link on of my node with this library to use my functions. What is the best
way to link the library?

First I complied the library:

``` $ g++ ``pkg-config --cflags opencv`` -o RailwayImageProcess.o -c RailwayImageProcess.c ``pkg-config --libs opencv`` ```

`$ g++ RailwayImageProcess.o -Wall -g -shared -o RailwayImageProcess.so`

Than i copied the *.so to /usr/local/lib

I tired adding to my CMakeList.txt the folowing lines:

`link_directories(/usr/local/lib)`

`target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}  RailwayImageProcess)`

Finally i run a `cmake .` and `make` But I get an error in Linking phase:
Linking CXX executable bin/railDetect
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lRailwayImageProcess
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/railDetect] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/railDetect.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104751/ho-to-export-external-library/) by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2013-11-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-11-25**:
What is your exact linking setup? Which libraries are involved. You have my_lib in the CMakeLists.txt, but you get an error on RailwayImageProcess. Do you have a dependency on that library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check for the *lib* prefix in your library name at linking phase.

---

Originally posted by [fapofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/9186/fapofa/) with karma: 36 on 2013-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1